# How to fix "Unexpected token... for architecture x86_64" error when running makefile

Tags: c++, macos, makefile, terminal, ld

I'm trying to install [HLA-LA](https://github.com/DiltheyLab/HLA-LA) on my 2016 MacBookPro (running Mojave 10.14.3) but I've been having issues compiling the makefile. I've installed all the dependencies, added the bamtools and boost paths as the README describes, and added CFLAGS to specify c++11. Still, when I run the makefile I get the following error:

```
$ make all
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.3.0/bin/g++-8  -I/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.68.0_1/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/bamtools/2.5.1/include/bamtools -I/usr/local/Cellar/bamtools/2.5.1/src -std=c++11 -ggdb -O2 -fopenmp -std=gnu++0x -fstack-protector-all HLA-LA.cpp -c -o ../obj/HLA-LA.o;
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.3.0/bin/g++-8  -I/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.68.0_1/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/bamtools/2.5.1/include/bamtools -I/usr/local/Cellar/bamtools/2.5.1/src -std=c++11 -ggdb -O2 -fopenmp -std=gnu++0x -fstack-protector-all ../obj/Edge.o ../obj/Graph.o ../obj/GraphAndEdgeIndex.o ../obj/Node.o ../obj/HaplotypePanel.o ../obj/simpleGraphSimulator.o ../obj/LocusCodeAllocation.o ../obj/simulator.o ../obj/readSimulator.o ../obj/trueReadLevels.o ../obj/processBAM.o ../obj/protoSeeds.o ../obj/oneRead.o ../obj/oneReadPair.o ../obj/oneReadPairwithSeedChains.o ../obj/alignerBase.o ../obj/alignmentContext.o ../obj/extensionAligner.o ../obj/BWAmapper.o ../obj/Bowtie2mapper.o ../obj/statistics.o ../obj/VirtualNWUnique.o ../obj/PRGContigBAMAlignment.o ../obj/verboseSeedChain.o ../obj/HLATyper.o ../obj/pathFinder.o ../obj/linearALTs.o ../obj/oneExonPosition.o ../obj/seedChain.o ../obj/Utilities.o  ../obj/HLA-LA.o -o ../bin/HLA-LA -L/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.68.0_1/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/bamtools/2.5.1/lib64 -L/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.11/lib -lboost_random -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system  -lbamtools -lz -lboost_serialization;
collect2: fatal error: ld terminated with signal 11 [Segmentation fault: 11]
compilation terminated.
ld: unexpected token: !tapi-tbd-v3 file '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd' for architecture x86_64
make: *** [HLA-LA] Error 1
```

I've seen [other people](https://github.com/neovim/homebrew-neovim/issues/190) with similar errors, but the recommended fixes havent worked. I've also tried specifying CLT via the path: `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib/` but it doesn't change the outcome at all. I read some thread that suggested it could be an `ld` issue but I'm not sure how I can fix that? Here are my specs:

```
macOS: 10.14.3-x86_64
CLT: 10.1.0.0.1.1539992718
Xcode: 10.1
```

Comment: Most likely one of your object files (the one containing `!tapi-tbd-v3`) was compiled with an option or symbol that is not compatible with x86_64 on mac. You will have to `grep` the source files that are compiled into object looking for `tapi-tbd-v3` -- which wouldn't be a legal single variable name. As written it would represent `tapi - tbd - v3` so there may be a translation issue where `tapi_tbd_v3` ended up mis-translated if it is supposed to be a single symbol.